# How to create an empty list in Idris REPL?

Tags: list, read-eval-print-loop, typechecking, idris, dependent-type

I want to create `myEmptyList` and `myNonemptyList` in REPL. However Idris reported a type mismatch error for `myEmptyList`. Why?

```
     ____    __     _                                          
    /  _/___/ /____(_)____                                     
    / // __  / ___/ / ___/     Version 1.3.0
  _/ // /_/ / /  / (__  )      http://www.idris-lang.org/      
 /___/\__,_/_/  /_/____/       Type :? for help               

Idris is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.            
For details type :warranty.
Idris> :let myEmptyList : List Integer = []
(input):1:33: When checking type of myEmptyList:
When checking argument y to type constructor =:
        Type mismatch between
                List elem (Type of [])
        and
                Type (Expected type)
(input):1:18:No type declaration for myEmptyList
Idris> :let myNonemptyList : List Integer = [42]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mismatch is because `:let myEmptyList : List Integer = []` does not define `myEmptyList`, it only declares its type as `List Integer = []`, an equality type, which is ill-typed because `[]` and `List Integer` have different types.

You can define `myEmptyList` as follows: `:let myEmptyList : List Integer; myEmptyList = []`, or alternatively `:let myEmptyList = the (List Integer) []`.

Comment: But why does `List Integer = [42]` compile?

Comment: A bug. It seems that Idris accepts that as a definition for `List` and ignores the `Integer`.

Comment: You can use `:let` to give a type without a definition, e.g. `:let x : Int`. And since `x = y` is a type, there's an ambiguity - it can either be parsed as `List Integer = []` the type, or the assignment.

Since there is an ambiguity, it's tried to parse it as an assignment first, then the type if the assignment fails. The assignment fails, so it tries to parse it as a type, which also fails.

I guess it should be clearer about reporting the ambiguity.

(Attempted edit: didn't realised that 'enter' posted, and I hadn't finished thinking about it. Sorry! Grrr.)

Comment: @EdwinBrady but what about `:let List Integer = [42]`? It seems to assign to `List` and ignore `Integer`, that sure isn't an intended behavior? Likewise `:let foo (List Integer) = 10`, for instance.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Hmm, I've no idea what that one is even trying to do. I'll define this behaviour more precisely in the new version.